# Prevent ShowDialog from closing the window in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window `myWindow`, which I open using `myWindow.ShowDialog() ?? true` and listen to the `DialogResult` (`DialogResult = true`) to execute some code.

When I set it to either `true` or `false`, the window is disposed, is there a way I can prevent this window from closing while also getting the `DialogResult`? Also, is there a another way I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to happen?  For example:

You might want a modal dialog (so users can't interact with the rest of the UI while it is visible) but you want code to run in the main program in response to some user action in the dialog.  In this case, add events to your dialog that the main program can respond to.

Or you might actually want a modeless dialog, which lets users interact with the rest of the program without completing the dialog.  In this case, don't use `ShowWindow`, just show an owned window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like to go with a modal dialog, but is there a way I can prevent the window from closing when I set dialogResult to true or false?  Otherwise, I'd like to go with a modeless window. In that case on window.Show() is there a way I can set similar to DialogResult to get a return value to the window.Show() call? Thanks

Comment: Please explain in broader terms what you're trying to achieve.